# how I display yfinancedata witout the Date

Tags: python, finance, stock, yfinance

```
import yfinance as yf
data = yf.download('AAPL')
print(data['Open'].tail(1).to_string())
```

the result is

```
Date            Open
2022-06-09    36.849998
```

I want to remove the date can anyone help me please?

Comment: Can you add expected output format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print(data['Open'].values[1])
```

the point is that the data is returned as a dataframe. If you want to extract a value, then use values in square brackets to specify the index. Since the indexes in this dataframe are dates, you can also extract them, for example:

```
print(data['Open'].index[1])
```